# TextFX HTML Tidy replacement (Format HTML)

Tags: html, notepad++, htmltidy

So it appears on several sites that TextFX's HTML tidy is both excellent and has also not been supported since 2008.

It appears that the latest version of Notepad++ completely breaks it in fact.

Now I've got some HTML on a single line that I need to indent, etc. any replacements for HTML Tidy on Notepad++ that anyone can recommend?

Comment: I am using HTML Tidy with NP++ v6.3 UNICODE and it seems to be working just fine. It does not cope with html5 though. I notice there is a plugin called Tidy2 which claims to support html5, but I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Try tidy2 (accessible from the plugin manager)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use [NppTidy2](https://github.com/davegb3/NppTidy2) plugin, it works pretty well.

Comment: It would be better to mention the name of the plugin (NppTidy) and a link to the SourceForge project (https://github.com/davegb3/NppTidy2) instead of only linking to the discussion. The link might become invalid and thus make your answer less useful.

Comment: This seems to be a sources only release. If you need a binary, google for "notepad++ npptidy2 binary". You will eventually find a thread in the [NP++ discussion board](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/2eeba3f3/) which leads to a [.zip package](https://github.com/downloads/davegb3/NppTidy2/Tidy2_0.1.zip)

Comment: The Plugin is in the plugin manager under the heading 'Tidy2' and works great!

Comment: Tidy2 will totally mess up any inline script elements by attempting to escape many of the characters.

Comment: Beware: Certain HTML character entities get replaced with their unicode character when you tidy. This is regardless of the Tidy2 configuration or document encoding. For example, "&#8217;" before tidying becomes "’" ("smart" single quote) after tidying. This made Tidy2 unusable for me. The project has not been updated since 2012.

Comment: The NppTidy2 version from bruderstein is outdated for years. An updated fork can be found here: https://github.com/geoffmcl/NppTidy2 - I edited the main post.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else stuck on this, in the end I used this tool

http://infohound.net/tidy/

Comment: that site does not seem to understand new html5 input types.

Answer (score 5):

Download old version notepad++ in zip format.
Copy from zip \unicode\plugins\Config\tidy 
to C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy

restart notepad++ and now you have available the plug-in

Menu -> TextFX -> TextFX HTML Tidy –> Tidy: Reindent XML

Link to download old version whit the plugin
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.6.8.html

Comment: This seemed like a good idea, but `TextFX HTML Tidy –> Tidy: Reindent XML` did not indent my javascript properly (didn't seem to do anything).